# Mesh is not rendering, I can only see a background image (or nothing)

Tags: rendering, objects, tracking

**FILE:**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vdiEmix_mWpaWA5m_V9n8wBDobLRzSB2/view?usp=sharing

I'm doing motion tracking scene and the objects that I put in are not rendering. They are rendering in viewport and in other places but not in the final render. The shadow catcher seems to not work too. I didn't pack the background movie, it's too heavy. 
 
I tried:

- [most of this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67491/102263)
- [realated question from

  blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/missing-object-when-rendering-a-camera-tracking-scene/610131)

1. FIRST Image is how it should looks like (taken from viewport)
2. SECOND is how it looks
   [image]

[image: This is how it should looks like]

Comment: Number 9 on the list. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67491/102263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off sequencer:

[image]

Once you have a movie clip in your VSE it will override rendering. If you want to composit your render on top of the footage, you need to use the compositor. Don't ask me why it's not off by default.

Comment: It's working now, thanks.